# Trouble replacing soundfont in Java - old soundfont still remains

Tags: java, midi, soundfont

I am trying to replace the default soundfont of a MIDI file with my own soundfont; however, the new soundfont plays on top of the old one rather than flat-out replacing the old one. My code:

```
Synthesizer synthesizer = MidiSystem.getSynthesizer();
synthesizer.open();
synthesizer.unloadAllInstruments(synthesizer.getDefaultSoundbank());
synthesizer.loadAllInstruments(MidiSystem.getSoundbank(new File("Airhorn.sf2")));

Sequencer sequencer = MidiSystem.getSequencer();
sequencer.open();
sequencer.getTransmitter().setReceiver(synthesizer.getReceiver());

InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File("Test.mid")));
sequencer.setSequence(inputStream);
sequencer.start();
```

Comment: Does "on top" mean that both instruments sound? And which Java implementation is this?

Comment: Yes both instruments sound. This is using the default Java MIDI implementation given in the JDK.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
MidiSystem.getSequencer(false)
```

to get your sequencer and prevent connecting it to the default device. Worked by me, JDK 8, Windows 10.